# When giving Height and width to png image, loses quality in react native

Tags: react-native

when i give height and width to png image, it loses quality. This is what i do

```
<Image
        source={require('../../../images/Icon.png')}
        style={{
          alignSelf: 'flex-end',
          resizeMode: 'contain', // i used 'cover' too 
          height: 48,
          width:48,
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

see, if you want your image to be of specific height and width, then its a bit difficult to actually obtain the exact image resolution.

But suppose you dont have that barrier , you can retain the image quality easily by applying the prop `aspectRatio` in the styles property of image :

For eg

```
<Image
source={..your source}
style={{
     height:100,
     aspectRatio: 16/9
 }}
resizeMode="cover"
 />
```

so you know the aspect ratio of the image, so just pass the image height/width(not both) and pass the aspect ratio